# How to compile a C program that uses a Framework without using Xcode

Tags: xcode, gcc, include-path

I have a C command line tool written in Xcode that uses the Accelerate Framework. It builds and runs as expected from Xcode. But when I try to compile it from the command line (using gcc), I get the error: `"Accelerate/Accelerate.h: No such file or directory"`. I don't know if adding the location of `Accelerate.h` to `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is the best way to fix this. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk` and then link with UIKit framework `-framework UIKit`.

You can check the actual build command line in Xcode build logs (option-7 in Xcode 4). Copy the one you need and adjust as required.

Also, build it with `xcodebuild` tool. It will find everything automatically like Xcode does.