# OSX How to compile a framework using GCC/G++ sitting in a current working directory or subdirectory C/C++

Tags: macos, gcc, frameworks, g++, working-directory

Hopefully this is an ok thing to do. But since I figured it out a while ago with much struggle and haven't yet seen it on stack overflow I figured I'd both post the question and answer.

This question/solution is for OSX users to compile a framework using GCC or G++ without needing to have the framework in the following path on their system

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will compile a framework from the listed directory in the question. (Answered before) [How to compile a C program that uses a Framework without using Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246823/how-to-compile-a-c-program-that-uses-a-framework-without-using-xcode)

```
gcc ...  -framework frameworkName a.c b.c ... -o out
```

This code will compile a framework from a custom directory. (Not Answered before as far as I've seen). Example of the following dir/file.

```
/alt/path/to/framework/frameworkName.framework
```

.

```
FLAGS+="-F /alt/path/to/framework/ -framework frameworkName rpath /alt/path/to/framework/"
gcc ...  $FLAGS a.c b.c ... -o out
```

This would be an example of a subdirectory of the working directory. I know ./ is usually the convention, but I cant remember if that worked for me or not here.

```
FLAGS+="-F $(PWD)/alt/path/to/framework/ -framework frameworkName rpath $(PWD)/alt/path/to/framework/"
gcc ...  $FLAGS a.c b.c ... -o out
```

This is a combination of the /System/Library/Frameworks/ path, and the path $(PWD)/alt/path/to/framework/ in the same compilation.

```
FLAGS+="-F $(PWD)/alt/path/to/framework/ -framework frameworkName2 rpath $(PWD)/alt/path/to/framework/"
gcc ...  -framework frameworkName1 $FLAGS a.c b.c ... -o out
```

If someone does locate this answer/question on stack overflow I will promptly delete my 'question'. The goal of this was to make portability of frameworks for people other than myself. How? Because if the framework is in a working directory, it can easily be moved around with the files/folder itself. It's obviously not a common thing people are trying, but maybe it'll make someones day.

Comment: `-rpath`, not `rpath`